# Instagram OAuth with thiago locatelli library

Tags: android, oauth, instagram

I am implementing instagram access in an Android application. So far the following library is used to get the access token, which seems to be quite popular.
https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth
In the Instagram Api guide I read "You should never ship your client secret onto devices you don’t control."

Isn't this what the library does, since it uses the client secret on user's device?
Can someone explain me, if/why this is legitim in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Would I did was create the client secret key at runtime.  Did the same thing with in-app purchases key.

Important: To keep your public key safe from malicious users and hackers, do not embed your public key as an entire literal string. Instead, construct the string at runtime from pieces or use bit manipulation (for example, XOR with some other string) to hide the actual key. The key itself is not secret information, but you do not want to make it easy for a hacker or malicious user to replace the public key with another key.